# How to get include a file outside the Android directory and use it in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a java program for both Android and JavaFX using a common core directory of code and a platform dependent section for each. One of these platform dependent options is called Resources, which is supposed to load text, image, and (eventually) audio files. The JavaFX version works great, and the skeleton of the program appears and can be used. However, the Android version won't doesn't display anything. I've traced that down to the fact that my resources aren't loading, throwing a variety of Exceptions, for the most part NullPointerExceptions. I'm not sure whether the problem is with the resources not being included or with giving it the wrong place to look in the program. My gradle file currently has the following relevant additions:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += '../../Both'
    main.res.srcDirs += '../../Resources'
}
```

The ../../Both directory properly gets built into the code, as it properly builds and runs, and the Both Directory and the Android directory uses it.
However, the Resources, which include (for the most part), a number of Art subdirectories.

I have tried the following code for reading the files, mostly from the javafx equivalent (which works):

```
private static String getPath(String resource)
{
    return "/Resources/"+resource;
}
public static ArrayList<String> loadText(String resource)
{
    try{
        if(filecache.containsKey(resource))
            return filecache.get(resource);
        InputStream in = R.getClass().getResourceAsStream(getPath(resource));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String t;
        while((t = reader.readLine()) != null)
            lines.add(t);
        filecache.put(resource, lines);
        return lines;
    } catch(Exception e){Debug.log(e.toString());}
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Using some code I found here, I have tried this as well, and a couple of variations of it, with no success. (using the same getPath() method)

```
ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new android.content.res.Resources().(getPath(resource));

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                res.add(receiveString);
            }
        }
        return res;
    } catch(Exception e){Debug.log("While opening: " + resource);Debug.log(e);}
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Both of those build, but throw Exceptions and don't load the files.
Any insights into how I might be able to read the files? Thanks!

Comment: From where you get file? internal storage? or external storage?

Comment: I'm trying to include the file with the program, so it would be internal storage. It's only external on my laptop relative to the Android directory.